# javascript objects sorting by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

Is there a way to sort array of objects in structure like:

```
var objs = [{
    "name": "B",
    "value": 1
}, {
    "name": "D",
    "value": "45"
}, {
    "name": "E",
    "value": "234"
}, {
    "name": "A",
    "value": "543"
}, {
    "name": "C",
    "value": "250"
}, {
    "name": "B",
    "value": 6
}, {
    "name": "D",
    "value": "234"
}, {
    "name": "E",
    "value": "67"
}, {
    "name": "A",
    "value": "78"
}, {
    "name": "C",
    "value": "12"
}];
```

by the elements in another array:

```
var orderedArray = ["E", "C", "B", "A", "D"];
```

in order to get structure like:

```
    {
            "name": "E",
            "value": "234"
        },
    {
            "name": "C",
            "value": "250"
        },
    {
            "name": "B",
            "value": 1
        },
{
        "name": "A",
        "value": "543"
    },
{
        "name": "D",
        "value": "45"
    },
{
        "name": "E",
        "value": "67"
    },
{
        "name": "C",
        "value": "12"
    },
{
        "name": "B",
        "value": 6
    },
{
        "name": "A",
        "value": "78"
    },
{
        "name": "D",
        "value": "234"
    }
```

I'm trying with sort() function by index of name key:

```js
var objs = [{ "name": "B", "value": 1 }, { "name": "D", "value": "45" }, { "name": "E", "value": "234" }, { "name": "A", "value": "543" }, { "name": "C", "value": "250" }, { "name": "B", "value": 6 }, { "name": "D", "value": "234" }, { "name": "E", "value": "67" }, { "name": "A", "value": "78" }, { "name": "C", "value": "12" }];

var orderedArray = ["E", "C", "B", "A", "D"];
var sorted = objs.sort((a, b) => orderedArray.indexOf(a.name) - orderedArray.indexOf(b.name));
console.log(sorted);
```

but the result isn't in the right order.

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwebster750/4gwnz20c/1/)

Comment: What's wrong with the order? It looks to be in the exact order specified by your `orderedArray`. **EDIT:** Note, I've also made your code into a runnable, inline snippet.

Comment: Can you give us more of your expected output? You show a single E followed by a single C followed by a single B. But there are more than one of each, so where are the others supposed to be?

Comment: They asked this same question yesterday

Comment: @Kobe The question yesterday seems *related* but not the same.

Comment: Given your edit, how do you know which `E` comes first, second, etc? Index?

Comment: Your ordering seems completely arbitrary. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and take the group and the order for getting a sequence sorting.

```js
var array = [{ name: "B", value: 1 }, { name: "D", value: "45" }, { name: "E", value: "234" }, { name: "A", value: "543" }, { name: "C", value: "250" }, { name: "B", value: 6 }, { name: "D", value: "234" }, { name: "E", value: "67" }, { name: "A", value: "78" }, { name: "C", value: "12" }],
    order = ["E", "C", "B", "A", "D"],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = array
        .map((o, i) => ({ index: i, order: order.indexOf(o.name), group: groups[o.name] = (groups[o.name] || 0) + 1 }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.order - b.order)
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```